# Дали задание, не могу решить (python)

Tags: python

Вводится натуральное число. Необходимо проверить, есть ли в этом числе какие-либо две одинаковые цифры. Вывести эти цифры, если они есть, иначе вывести 'НЕТ'

Answer (score 1):

Напиши если будут баги, но поидее должно работать

```
n = int(input())

found = False
numbers = set()
while n != 0:
    num = n % 10
    n //= 10
    if num in numbers:
        print(num)
        found = True
    numbers.add(num)

if not found:
    print('НЕТ')
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)

Comment: `break` надо убрать, чтобы код работал с числами в которых более одной одинаковой цифра (`5577`)

Comment: @Danis Да, вы правы, отредактировал. Спасибо